# selenium size['width'] returns zero for elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium with python, using a Chrome webdriver to read a static html file on my disk. Some elements behave well when `.size['width']` is called upon them, returning the widths with no problem. But multiple of elements, whose css width property is "auto", returns zero when I call `e.size['width']` for such an element `e`. Why? And how can I get the actual width of the elements? They are definitely not zero (as can be seen from the Chrome developer tools' popover tooltips) and `e.value_of_css_property("width")` returns "auto", which isn't informative.

Comment: I don't think it typically would return 0 with that code... Is there any chance you're grabbing the wrong element that is maybe a parent or child of the one that has a width?

Comment: That it's not typical is also what confuses me. There is no chance I'm grabbing the wrong element. For each element I printed the xpath, the class properties, the css properties, and the Selenium-perceived width from .size, all together, just to double-check. All these elements have "auto" width from css and 0 width from Selenium.

Comment: I ask because `auto` can definitely resolve to 0, and fairly frequently I've found that the element that looks like the one I want actually has a size of 0 and the one I actually want is close by on the hierarchy

Comment: Right but it's not the case here. They don't resolve to zero.

Answer (score 1):

I found out somehow this is to do with my specifying the option of headless for selenium:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

remove the `options.add_argument('headless')` line, and the sizes, including widths, spring back to life. Anyone knows why this is the case, and is there a way to both remain headless and get non-zero widths from `.size['width']` for elements that do have non-zero width?

Comment: Headless browsers don't load a gui, so it makes sense that nothing would have a size. Good catch :)

Answer (score 0):

did you use something like:

```
driver.set_window_size(1366, 768)
```

for defining window size?
and what is *e* please post your code so we can help you better

Comment: OP mentioned that `e` is an element. [webelement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html)

Comment: I did not. But I don't think window_size matters. After all, some elements do have width from `e.size['width']`. It's just that some don't, despite that Chrome developer tool and human eyeballs would both say they have width. I doubt my entire code would help either except to serve as a distraction -- the snippet I already posted is all there is.